# when i finish my code i have this warrnings how to fix it?

Tags: javascript, eslint

my teacher give me quest to done

but when I finish my quest but when i done i get 2 warnings and my teacher dont like any warnings

anyone can help me how i fix this warnings ?

i try add to 2nd error

```
function (obj) {
```

or

```
obj =>
```

but still not remove warning

1st warning

> The object literal notation {} is preferable. (W010)

[image: 1st warning]

2nd warning

> Functions declared within loops referencing an outer scoped variable may lead to confusing semantics. (a2, valslice, tit, a1) (W083)

[image: 2nd warning]

Comment: What is the message? Do you see anything in the errors / messages panel in your IDE or in the compiler output? If nothing else, hover over the squiggly lines with your mouse and see if something pops up.

Comment: Please visit the [help] to see what and [ask]. HINT: Post effort and **CODE** not PICTURES of code. Mouse over the code to see what the warnings are and tell us

Comment: The object literal notation {} is preferable. (W010)

Comment: Functions declared within loops referencing an outer scoped variable may lead to confusing semantics. (a2, valslice, tit, a1) (W083)

Comment: In 2nd, test if __id instanceof Array instead of typeof __id ==="object"

Comment: `let dob = {};` is the answer to #1 - exactly as the warning said

Comment: @FrV i try not fix :(

Comment: Make a real function instead of lambda expression:` __id.forEach(handling)`
`function handling(item){...}`

Comment: @FrV if i use function i cant edit above variable :(

Comment: What you can do to keep variable available is to declare the function inner the function then pass it in the forEach

Comment: @FrV please could you show me small example ?

Answer (score 0):

Example for the 2nd Warning

In my opinion use lambda expression is not wrong but you can try this:

```
function example(){
    let a2, valslice, mongoose, tit, __id; // what you use in your lambda expression
    // ... code, init ...
    function forEachHandler(item){
        // what is in your lambda expression
    }

    __id.forEach(forEachHandler);
}
```

An other approach is to declare function as usual and use `__id.forEach(fn.bind({/*this*/}, ...args))`

Answer (score 0):

change the first one to `let dob = {}`